# How do I Make a gif run on hdmi on loop

Tags: command-line, server, scripts, raspberrypi, gif

I Have a Raspberry Pi with an Ubuntu Server on it and I want it to loop a gif from a command to HDMI

Comment: A server has no X-server (or wayland). How and where do you want to paint on? Only way I could think of is a webpage, which you could call from your client. But a Linux server doing graphics natively? What sense does this make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for my inaccurate question.

The correct question is what is the most lightweight way to get an image open with Ubuntu server.

Now that I have researched my project more I can say the fastest way to view an image from an Ubuntu server is to install Openbox and VLC for the lightest and most customizable setup.

I appreciate JA01201812 for pointing out that I need a window manager to display my images

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for something like the top answer at this link below.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35333/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-view-images-from-the-terminal

In short, there are a number of ways to open images from the command line, like the xdg-open, eog, or feh commands.

As implied by kanehekili and David, any of these require a desktop environment of some kind as they open application windows.